# det function in concave

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $f(A)=(\det(A))^{\frac{1}{n}}$. And assume domain of $f$ is space of positive semi definite symmetric $n\times n$ matrices with real entries. Show that $f$ is concave: 
$$f((1-t)A+tB)) \ge (1-t)f(A)+tf(B)$$
for $t \in [0,1]$.

Comment: I think you want positive semi-definite symmetric matrices.

Comment: Yes. Positive semidefinite symmetric matrices.

Answer (score 2):

Hint 1

> You should prove it for the case where neither of the two matrices is symmetric positive definite first and then assume one is positive definite.

Hint 2:

> You can simultaneously diagonalise a symmetric positive definite matrix and a symmetric one. Can you prove it?

Hint 3:

> You can consider the positive definite one as the matrix of a scalar product. What does it look like in an orthonormal basis? And what form can the other matrix take in an orthonormal basis?

Hint 4:

> Try using the spectral theorem.

Comment: Could we differentiate $det(Id+tA)$(with respect to $t$)?

Comment: Well at that point $A$ is diagonal so  $f((1-t)I_n+tA)=\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n ((1-t)+t\lambda_k)}$, and $(1-t)f(I_n)+tf(A)=(1-t)+t\sqrt[n]{\prod\limits_{k=1}^n \lambda_k}$ with the $\lambda_k$ being the eigenvalues of $A$.